# PyScript always download Pyodide everytime HTML page is refreshed leading to slow loading time

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I'm trying to run PyScript in a webpage, where I intended it to run and produce the output of a python code to a div element. I've succeeded in doing this. However I noticed it always produces the splashscreen "Downloading Pyodide Python Startup" every time I refreshed the webpage. It's taking significantly longer wait time for this.

Is there a way to in a way cache the Pyodide installation and make the loading times significantly faster? I'm deploying this webpage to Github Pages here https://reza-nugraha32.github.io/geophysics-wiki/
.

I'm aware that it's not better to hide the splash screen entirely. Is there also a way to start this splash screen in a div container or importing the PyScript only when a "Run" button is clicked? For instance, Educative.io [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-pass-variable-data-from-a-python-code-to-html-in-pyscript) made it so it display "Loading" only when the "Run" button is clicked.

I've tried deleting the `defer` tag from the PyScript import script but it gave me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Reza, but that's just the way it works. The whole environment has to be downloaded before any code runs. Pyscript Next (2023.11.1) may improve your situation, especially if you can use Micropython. Check out Jeff Glass's blog - https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2023-11-1/.

Comment: Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the documentation:
https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/plugins/py-splashscreen.html

you can disable the splash screen using the following html code:

```
<py-config>
    [splashscreen]
        enabled = false
</py-config>
```

hope this helps!